# Replace missing values with the mean of each variable Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I would like to: Replace missing values with the mean I've tried this :

```
num_df.fillna(num_df.mean())
```

But I still have missing values

````
{'id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}, 'age': {0: 48.0, 1: 7.0, 2: 62.0, 3: 48.0}, 'bp': {0: 80.0, 1: 50.0, 2: 80.0, 3: 70.0}, 'al': {0: 1.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 4.0}, 'su': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 0.0}, 'bgr': {0: 121.0, 1: nan, 2: 423.0, 3: 117.0}, 'bu': {0: 36.0, 1: 18.0, 2: 53.0, 3: 56.0}, 'sc': {0: 1.2, 1: 0.8, 2: 1.8, 3: 3.8}, 'sod': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 111.0}, 'pot': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 2.5}, 'hemo': {0: 15.4, 1: 11.3, 2: 9.6, 3: 11.2}, 'pcv': {0: '44', 1: '38', 2: '31', 3: '32'}, 'wc': {0: '7800', 1: '6000', 2: '7500', 3: '6700'}, 'rc': {0: '5.2', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: '3.9'}} ```
````

num_df.fillna(num_df.mean())

````
```{'id': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}, 'age': {0: 48.0, 1: 7.0, 2: 62.0, 3: 48.0}, 'bp': {0: 80.0, 1: 50.0, 2: 80.0, 3: 70.0}, 'al': {0: 1.0, 1: 4.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 4.0}, 'su': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 0.0}, 'bgr': {0: 121.0, 1: 148.0365168539326, 2: 423.0, 3: 117.0}, 'bu': {0: 36.0, 1: 18.0, 2: 53.0, 3: 56.0}, 'sc': {0: 1.2, 1: 0.8, 2: 1.8, 3: 3.8}, 'sod': {0: 137.52875399361022, 1: 137.52875399361022, 2: 137.52875399361022, 3: 111.0}, 'pot': {0: 4.627243589743592, 1: 4.627243589743592, 2: 4.627243589743592, 3: 2.5}, 'hemo': {0: 15.4, 1: 11.3, 2: 9.6, 3: 11.2}, 'pcv': {0: '44', 1: '38', 2: '31', 3: '32'}, 'wc': {0: '7800', 1: '6000', 2: '7500', 3: '6700'}, 'rc': {0: '5.2', 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: '3.9'}}```
````

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your dataframe _as [formatted](/help/formatting) text_ so that people can copy it into their environments and test their solutions on your dataframe. Your dataframe can't be recreated from screenshots of text

Comment: What do you expect for the average of a column with all nans?

Comment: I would like to replace the NaN with the average of each column

Comment: My dataframe is larger than the screenshot I made, it doesn't only have Nan's, however my technique didn't replace the Nan's in my rc column

Comment: Can you `print(num_df.head(4).to_dict())` (before your fillna attempt) and paste the output in your question as a dataframe builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last few columns are strings, not floats.

Try converting to float before taking the `mean`:

```py
# Make Sure Everything is numeric
num_df = num_df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
# Take Mean
num_df = num_df.fillna(num_df.mean())

print(num_df)
```

```
   id    sod  pot  hemo  pcv    wc    rc
0   0  111.0  2.5  15.4   44  7800  5.20
1   1  111.0  2.5  11.3   38  6000  4.55
2   2  111.0  2.5   9.6   31  7500  4.55
3   3  111.0  2.5  11.2   32  6700  3.90
```

Comment: I have this error message : ```TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NAType' ``` in this line ```num_df = num_df.astype(float)```

Comment: Try now with to_numeric

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]

I understand the actual problem, fillna(df.mean()) fills the nan values with mean of the column. You have columns with all nan values. So you get the nan values after fillna(df.mean()) method.

I tried your method with a random example shown in below;

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = [[np.nan, np.nan, 15, 4], [1,2,3,4], [10,20,np.nan,30]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
```

It works because I have no fully nan column.

Comment: unfortunately this method does not replace all missing values...some columns keep Nan

Comment: @kevincaro I understand the problem, and updated my answer.

Comment: It's not because of that, because my rc column still has those Nan